# how are integers seen in RAM?

Tags: c, arrays, int

I mean an `int` is actually a 4 byte 'box' in memory (well, almost always 4 bytes), but how are they distinguished from one another? Well, I guess since they are 32 bits long, the compiler knows that after each 32 bits another `int` starts and so on (this is just an assumption so correct me if I'm wrong) but then it occurs to me, how are arrays of integers distinguished from other arrays of integers and from other integers, i.e. how the does the compiler know when an array of integers starts and ends?

Strings of characters, for example, are separated by \0 chars, but what happens for ints and arrays of ints?

Maybe I haven't been clear to what I mean to ask: I'm asking, if we have an array, say of 3 integers, let's say that they are in memory from 0x145 to 0x151. Suppose now, from 0x151 to 0x155 there is another int. how does the compiler know that the `int` that goes from 0x151 to 0x155 is not part of the array? And thus if we try to access it through the bracket notation a segmentation fault error may raise?

Comment: my *guess* would be the same thing (since we get an index out of bounds exception). But this is ***entirely*** guessed

Comment: the "computer" does not know.  It is just a bunch of sequential memory.  The app needs to keep track of that.

Comment: @Root149 if this is `c`, then the compiler doesn't know either. at least it doesn't know where it ends

Comment: who knows then, and how? more clarity please

Comment: @Root149 I suggest to take a look at my answer

Comment: You need a *really* powerful microscope.

Comment: This is a great, thoughtful foundational question about programming. I'm astounded that it's been downvoted.

Comment: Learn assembly language and it will become clearer.

Comment: *who knows then, and how? more clarity please* -- One hopes that the programmer knows.  (I often state that C doesn't really implement arrays, just a fiction based on pointers.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to understand this concept clearly, you should take a computer architecture course, or read a computer architecture book.  It will de-mystify a lot of how computers work.

But for a simple answer:  The computer knows where your array starts due to a pointer, which is essentially a value representing an address in memory.  The pointer is stored in another place in memory, and that place is allocated by the OS.

---

It knows where to access indexed integers at because it know the exact length of each integer, and it assumes that the elements in the array are contiguous.

So if you have 32-bit ints, and the first int is at address A, then the next int will be at the address 32 bits after A.

---

In my experience, your program itself doesn't actually know where the array ends in `c`.  That's why you can sometimes see artifacts that look like data from other arrays and other values from other places in your application appearing in your array if you the programmer don't actually keep track of it.  It's also why your compiler will let you access values that are not allocated to your program(in which case you'll get a segmentation fault at runtime)

Comment: but does not a pointer to an array of integers keep the address of only the first byte of the first integers in the array?

Comment: @Root149 yes, it does.  It assumes that the integers are contiguous from that point on

Comment: and then, how do we know where it ends? if we keep the address of the first byte only. that is my question

Comment: @Root149 It normally doesn't know where it ends.  Have you ever tried to compile a program that tries to access values after the array ends?  It will compile just fine.

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear to what I mean to ask: I'm asking, if we have an array, say of 3 integers, let's say that they are in memory from 0x145 to 0x157. Suppose now, from 0x157 to 0x161 there is another int. how does the compiler know that the int that goes from 0x157 to 0x161 is not part of the array? And thus if we try to access it through the bracket notation a segmentation fault error raises?

Comment: @Root149 it doesn't know.  If you access the `A[3]`, you might very well get the value that you would get if you accessed `B[0]`

Comment: The compiler doesn't know. The OS can detect a memory violation in case this memory is not allocated for process. Or if you are trying to modify some data, which belongs to some other stuff, it will eventually corrupt something and you will get the error

Comment: @Root149 of course, this is just `c` we're talking about.  There are other languages actually do know where the end of the array is.  There's nothing stopping the program from using 2 or more contiguous words(ints) to store whatever metadata they want about the array, including type, length, timestamp, etc

Comment: @SamIam SOME of the other languages. And some of them can be tricked.

Comment: @Root149 You might be thinking that you'll *always* get a segmentation fault when you access values outside the array, but in reality you'll get a segmentation fault *only* if what you try to access happens to be something the program isn't allowed to access.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, an `int` might not always have the size of 4 bytes.

For example an integer on an `i8051` is just 16 bit in size.

Your question is very hard to answer since there is a lot you need to know to fully understand how this works. How such types are *seen in RAM* depend on the architecture but can also depend on the compiler.

What a compiler does is translating your code *for* a specific architecture. Therefore there are many different compilers which have to take care of many different architectures.

You can use

```
gcc -o main *.c
```

To compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    char b;
};

int main()
{
    struct MyStruct strct;
    
    strct.a = 0x1337;
    strct.b = 'a';

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
objdump -M intel -d main
```

to create a dump file:

```
00000000004004f0 <main>:                                                                                  
  4004f0:       55                      push   rbp                                                        
  4004f1:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp                                                    
  4004f4:       c7 45 f0 0a 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x1337                                   
  4004fb:       c6 45 f4 61             mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0xc],0x61                                    
  4004ff:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0                                                    
  400504:       5d                      pop    rbp                                                        
  400505:       c3                      ret                                                               
  400506:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]                                
  40050d:       00 00 00
```

The two instructions:

```
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x1337                                   
mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0xc],0x61
```

represent

```
strct.a = 0x1337;
strct.b = 'a';     // becomes value 0x61 in hex
```

and as you can see, the compiler translated it into addresses: e.g. `[rbp-0x10]` ([indirect memory operands](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Addressing/lecture.html)) is an address inside your RAM and the hex value `0x1337` (*note that these are only 2 bytes but the whole `int` is going to consume 4 bytes*) gets written there using the [`mov`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_addressing_modes.htm) instruction. [`DWORD`](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/DataTypes/lecture.html#T77_0120_allocation_directives_cont) means here 32 bit.

### How it looks in Memory (e.g. RAM):

Let us assume that `rbp`, which is a pointer to the [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), has the address `0x10000010` (I chose this arbitrary) then your memory looks at some point like:

```
      Memory address  | hex value (single bytes)
-------------------------------------------------
[rbp-0x10] 0x10000000 : 00 
           0x10000001 : 00
           0x10000002 : 13
           0x10000003 : 37
[rbp-0x0C] 0x10000004 : 61 
           ...
[rbp]      0x10000010 : ?? // stack base pointer (can be anything)
```

As you can see, the bytes `0x10000000` to `0x10000003` are the four bytes corresponding to `strct.a` whereas `0x10000004` is the byte we addressed with `strct.b`.

This is of course not everything you have to know in order to fully understand how Architecture, Compiler and even Linker play together. If you are really interested in understanding this better I would recommend you to learn just a few basics in *assembly*. This helped me a lot to understand this matter.

As you can see: The "*computer*" has no idea of integers or struct. It mostly depends on the instructions that the compiler translated the program into. In the end it is the *actual* binary code that "*interprets*" the values inside RAM as the *program* **commands** it to!

Comment: ++, though I'd replace "RAM" with "memory" as what's visible for a C programmer aren't necessarily hardware addresses.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler, as you point out, knows, given the target architecture, the size of various types. So, for example;

```
int a = 9;
int b = 3;
printf("%d, %d\n"), a,b);
```

Might, in a very simple compiler (No optimisation) generate target machine instructions like:

```
mov  ax,_data_start
mov  bx,_data_start+4    ; Size of an int
call _printf
```

Take a look at http://gcc.godbolt.org  , where you can type some high level C, and see the assembler output...

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the data is not "distinguished" by it's representation in the memory. Lets assume that we are talking about a byte-aligned or packed memory architecture, then you could have an array of bytes defined as

```
char c[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};
```

Then if you cast `c` to an integer pointer:

```
int i = *((int*)c);
```

you will get the integer composed of first 4 bytes, i.e. 
`0x04030201` (if we are little-endian)
But you can do something like

```
int i = *((int*)(c+1));
```

Then you will have i=0x05040302, since the integer now is read starting from the next byte.
So, a value in the memory has a specific type only when we tell to the compiler that in this specific address we have the first byte of a variable of a specific type, and then it knows how to take it and interpret.

Answer (score 1):

In C. the compiler *doesn't* know where an array (of integers or anything else) ends -- that's why you get undefined behavior for out-of-bounds accesses.  You need to tell the compiler explicitly where the array ends (by telling it a length) and if you get it wrong, bad things happen.

`char` arrays are no different, notwithstanding the use of `'\0'` to mark the end of strings -- the length of a string and the length of the array the string currently resides in are not necessarily connected in any way, and you can copy a string that is too big for the destination array with no complaint from the compiler -- you just get undefined behavior for overrunning the array, so anything might happen.

In your example of an array from 0x145 to 0x151 and an integer from 0x151 to 0x155, the compiler doesn't (necessarily) know this, so it's likely that an index off the end of the array will *not* cause a segfault and will just access the following integer. That's why it's undefined behavior -- anything might happen.